# Spring-boot how to import all i18n messages of all jar dependencys projects?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, internationalization

I want to import all the messages.properties files, which are contained in the src/main/resource/messages locations of ALL the jar dependencies of my project.
for example:
Project A import -> Project B, and I need to load all message properties.

I tried:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages", "classpath:/messages/messages");
  messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
  return messageSource;
}
```

But it did not work =(.How can I do this with spring-boot?

Here's my project structure:

```
project A
+-- project-server-business
¦   +-- src
¦   ¦   +-- main
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- java
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- resources
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- messages
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  +-- messages-business.properties
¦   +-- pom.xml
+-- project-server-service
¦   +-- src
¦   ¦   +-- main
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- java
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- resources
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- messages
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  +-- messages-business.properties
¦   +-- pom.xml
+-- pom.xml

project B
+-- project-server-business
¦   +-- src
¦   ¦   +-- main
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- java
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- resources
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- messages
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  +-- messages-business.properties
¦   +-- pom.xml
+-- project-server-service
¦   +-- src
¦   ¦   +-- main
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- java
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- resources
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +-- messages
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  +-- messages-business.properties
¦   +-- pom.xml
+-- pom.xml
```

My pom build structure:

```
<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src${file.separator}main${file.separator}resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.plugin.target}</source>
                        <target>${maven.plugin.target}</target>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.plugin.target}</source>
                    <target>${maven.plugin.target}</target>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Comment: I'm interest in this as well... have you solve it?

Comment: Yeah, but i don't have the solution right now, this is a old project. I'll search the project and post answer here.